# How to Get the total number of (the differnece between two dates)?

Tags: sql, date, informix

I i have a table [holidays] with the following structure :

> id | start_date | end_date | user_id

How to get the number of holidays for a user in the previous year ?

I wanna something like that with correct syntax:

```
SELECT SUM(end_date - start_date)
FROM holidays
WHERE user_id = 342
    AND YEAR(end_date) = YEAR(CURRENT) - 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work in informix:

```
SELECT SUM(end_date-start_date)
from holidays
where user_id = 342 and
     YEAR(end_date) = YEAR(TODAY)-1;
```

Note:  it is not clear whether the end date is inclusive or not.  You might want:

```
SELECT SUM((end_date-start_date) + 1)
from holidays
where user_id = 342 and
     YEAR(end_date) = YEAR(TODAY)-1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is perfectly fine. You don't have any syntax improvements to be done. The only thing Gordon Linoff's approach (which will work) differs from yours is that he is using `TODAY` (that is `YEAR TO DAY`) instead of `CURRENT` (that is `YEAR TO FRACTION`), but `YEAR(CURRENT)` and `YEAR(TODAY)` would get the exact same result.

The only way you would get a different result was if you had `CURRENT` inside the `SUM`, like  `SUM(CURRENT-start_date)`. That way you would have more precision than only the days (You would get the days and then hh:mm:ss.fff) like you want, but if you used `TODAY`, you would get only the days.

Other than that, it's perfectly fine.